# VBA like AutoHotKeys Features

Tags: excel, vba, automation, autohotkey

OK, revised my old question better:: deleted the other one. I am still new to coding and have kinda put this together from other things I found online. I am trying to make a AHK style mouse mover and clicker. The moving and clicking works, but I can't get it to click and drag (to highlight things) and can't get the copy/paste to work. This is on work computer and I can not use AHK so making it in VBA.

```
NOT CODE BUT Stack made me indent!!! Spreadsheet layout:    
ColA = x coordinates 
Cold = y coordinates 
ColC = Sleep
ColD = Click down only. (to highlight something)  
ColE = Click up only. (to highlight something) 
ColF = copy
ColG = Paste
ColJ = Enter
```

It keeps giving me an error on `j = Range(theAddressJ).Value` But I don't know why.

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32" 
(ByVal X As      Long, ByVal Y As Long) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwFlags As      
Long, ByVal dx As Long, ByVal dy As Long, ByVal cButtons As Long, ByVal 
dwExtraInfo As Long)
Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = &H2
Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = &H4
Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN As Long = &H8
Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP As Long = &H10
 
 
 
Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
 
 
 
Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" (lpPoint As  
POINTAPI) As Long
 
Public Type POINTAPI
 
X As Long
 
Y As Long
 
End Type
 
 
Sub Move()
 
Dim LastRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
 
 
Dim i As Integer
Dim a As Integer
Dim b As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim d As String
Dim e As String
Dim f As String
Dim g As String
Dim j As String
Dim theAddressA As String
Dim theAddressB As String
Dim theAddressC As String
Dim theAddressD As String
Dim theAddressE As String
Dim theAddressF As String
Dim theAddressG As String
Dim theAddressJ As String
 
i = 2
 
Do While i <= LastRow
 
theAddressA = "A" & CStr(i)
theAddressB = "B" & CStr(i)
theAddressC = "C" & CStr(i)
theAddressD = "D" & CStr(i)
theAddressE = "E" & CStr(i)
theAddressF = "F" & CStr(i)
theAddressG = "G" & CStr(i)
theAddressG = "J" & CStr(i)
 
a = Range(theAddressA).Value
b = Range(theAddressB).Value
c = Range(theAddressC).Value
d = Range(theAddressD).Value
e = Range(theAddressE).Value
f = Range(theAddressF).Value
g = Range(theAddressG).Value
j = Range(theAddressJ).Value
 
 
 
SetCursorPos a, b
    If Not Range(theAddressD) = "" Then
        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
        mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
    End If
 
    If Not Range(theAddressE) = "" Then
        mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
    End If
   
Sleep c
 
If Not Range(theAddressF) = "" Then
SendKeys "^(C)"
End If
If Not Range(theAddressG) = "" Then
SendKeys "^(V)"
End If
If Not Range(theAddressJ) = "" Then
SendKeys "(ENTER)"
End If
 
Sleep 700
 
i = i + 1
Loop
 
 
End Sub
```

I also want to know if someone can help me with a click recorder so I don't have to keep manually finding the pixels and writing them down to input in cells, maybe something that just recorded the clicks like AHK can do to make these things faster. Any help is appreciated.

Wish I could just download AHK but not worth risking it with this company

Comment: Your code is referencing 'theAddressG =' twice (where 2nd instance should probably be theAddressJ).

Comment: That did work, thank you, but also the click and drag doesn't work nor the copy/paste????

Comment: Can you explain why you actually need that? There might be other more convenient ways to solve you ractual issue.

Comment: For copy-pasting, it seems you are trying it with shifted (capital) shortcut keys.  I'm not sure it makes much difference for "paste," but copying doesn't appear to work with '^+c' equiv to '^C' like you have (the shift '+' capitalizes the 'c').